# Sala de chat, permisos a usuarios sin reputación suficiente

Tags: bug, chat

Hice una sala de chat que sirva de mesa de ayuda a usuarios nuevos. [Aquí](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32679/ayuda-a-usuarios-nuevos).

El problema que tengo es al intentar agregar usuarios a la lista de *Write Access*. Segun entiendo por la descripción:

*Even when this room is read-only **or their reputation is too low**, these users will be able to talk in this room.*

debería poder agregarlos.

Sin embargo cuando busco el usuario por nombre e intento darle permisos de escritura me dice:

### Users must have at least 20 reputation to talk

Se puede solucionar?

Comment: interesante pregunta - déjame investigar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para poder agregar a usuarios nuevos con las condiciones mencionadas se necesitan los permisos de un Moderador.  El ir agregando a los usuarios uno por uno no es un sistema escalable.  Pensemos mejor en otra solución.

Comment: Juan, la sala "ayuda a usuarios nuevos" esta apareciendo en la pagina: lista de preguntas. Ya que la solución no va a funcionar, sería mejor eliminarla y evitar la confusion.

Comment: @rnrneverdies cierto - permíteme investigar eso

Comment: La sala de chat la he removido.